# onmouseover for ipad

Tags: ios, onmouseover

```
<a href="http://boosterads.co.uk/newsite/" tooltop="dashboard" tooltip="dashboard">
<img src="http://boosterads.co.uk/newsite/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/homelight.png"  class="headerlogo" onmouseover="this.src='http://boosterads.co.uk/newsite/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/homedark.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://boosterads.co.uk/newsite/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/homelight.png'" /></a>
```

I am using this code to change an image onmouseover. Does anyone know what i need to include for it to work on iphones/ipads?

i.e. the user clicks once and the hover displays, they click again and they are sent to the link.

Comment: Usually you would just make that a button. If tapped it should take you to the link. I'm surprised it isn't doing that already.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would have to define what a "click" was, as tapping on a ipad is equivalent to clicking on a computer.  This means that currently, your code would take a use straight to the link when they hover their mouse over the image (using a mouse) and on an ipad, there is no way to hover over an image, as there is no curser.  the only way I can think of to get round this is to find some code (I don't know any myself) which adds a curser to your webpage when it is used on a mobile device.  Hope this helps :)